# Do I need SSL with Virtumart if I don't use a payment method?

Tags: ssl, joomla, https, certificate, shopping-cart

I have been creating a rewards system in virtumart where users can claim rewards using their points.

Instead of paying with money, Virtumart has a add-on which creates my points system as currency. So no need for credit cards etc.

I have not finished the project yet, but if I click "Checkout" from the cart menu, my browser warns me that I might be entering an unsecured site (no HTTPS).

Is there a way to avoid this warning since no payments will be made? Or do I have to purchase an SSL certificate?

Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable "Secure Checkout" in VirtueMart's store settings and you should be OK. If you don't want an SSL on your checkout pages, then you are not forced to use it with VirtueMart.